# Reg: Neo4j display null values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and graph databases. I am trying to create a simple graph DB, but my `MATCH` query is returning `null` values. How do I avoid `null`s or any errors in my coding?

## Create DB

```
CREATE
  (d2:CorNode:course:dscor{Cors_Name:'DataScience_Sem2',Start_Date:'January2018',No_Students:[tointeger(10)]})-[:sem2dsrelation{Name:'Semester2',Cor_Name:'Data Science',A_Y:'AY2017-18',Cor_Node:'CMM534'}]->(Rob:FLNode:course:dscor{Name_F:'Rob Lothian', Role:'Leader',Mod_code:'CMM534'}),
  (d2)-[:sem2dsrelation{Name:'Semester2', Cor_Name:'Data Science',A_Y:'AY2017-18',Cor_Node:'CMM534'}]->(Eyad:FLNode:course:dscor{Name_F:'Eyad Elyan',Role:'Leader',Mod_code:'CMM534'}),
  (d2)-[:sem2dsrelation{Name:'Semester2', Cor_Name:'Data Science',A_Y:'AY2017-18',Cor_Node:'CMM507'}]->(David:FLNode:course:dscor{Name_F:'David Lonie', Role:'Leader', Mod_code:'CMM507'}),
  (d2)-[:sem2dsrelation{Name:'Semester2',Cor_Name:'Data Science', A_Y:'AY2017-18',Cor_Node:'CMM535'}]->(Rob),
  (d1:CorNode:course:dscor{Cors_Name:'DataScience_Sem1',Start_Date:'Septemer2017',No_Students:[tointeger(25)]})-[:sem1dsrelation{Name:'Semester1',Cor_Name:'Data Science',A_Y:'AY2017-18',Cor_Node:'CMM524'}]->(Rob),
  (d1)-[:sem1dsrelation{Name:'Semester1', Cor_Name:'Data Science',A_Y:'AY2017-18',Cor_Node:'CMM531'}]->(Eyad),
  (d1)-[:sem1dsrelation{Name:'Semester1', Cor_Name:'Data Science',A_Y:'AY2017-18',Cor_Node:'CMM510'}]->(Ines:FLNode:course:dscor{Name_F:'Ines Arana',Role:'Leader',Mod_code:'CMM510'})
```

## Query DB

```
MATCH (:dscor)-[ds1:sem1dsrelation{Name:'Semester1',Cor_Name:'Data Science'}]-(FLNode:dscor)
RETURN DISTINCT [FLNode.Name_F,ds1.Cor_Node]
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have a typo. In `(FLNode:dscor)`, "FLNode" is being used a a variable name instead of as a label.

To fix this, you need to assign a variable name (say, `x`) to the node, make sure `FLNode` is specified to be a label (by putting a `:` in front of it), and then use `x` in the result. Like so:

```
MATCH (:dscor)-[ds1:sem1dsrelation{Name:'Semester1',Cor_Name:'Data Science'}`]-(x:FLNode:dscor)
RETURN DISTINCT [x.Name_F,ds1.Cor_Node];
```